# Why does django require that I create a mysql database just to run the tests?

Tags: django

When using sqlite for django you can checkout your application from source control and run the unit tests without needed to do anything special. But when you switch to using mysql as your database all of the sudden you need to create a database. Why do I need to do this? This is especially weird since the unit tests won't even use that database, they will instead create their own by prefixing the name with 'test_'.

Answer (score 1):

This is because Django loads the settings.py file for running the test suite. You can create a separate settings.py file and use it at the time you run the tests. As an example from the django site:

```
--settings=test_sqlite
```

assuming you had a settings.py file called test_sqlite.

Go here for more information:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/unit-tests/

Comment: I have a separate settings file and I still want to use mysql instead of sqlite for testing since the databases are different enough that I want to tests against the database engine that I'm deploying to.

Comment: You need to create a database for using mysql and postgres. In sqllite, when you go to make a connection to the db, connection('database') if it doesn't exist, it will get created. During the unittests, they will create their own tables within the database, once complete the unit tests should teardown the tables.

Comment: Yeah I get that, but the question is: Why?

Comment: It's a feature of the database(s) it has nothing to do with Django. Sqlite is written where if a database doesn't exist, it will create one. In postgres, if you attempt to connect to a database that doesn't exist, you get an error. Same in mysql.

Comment: That's weird since the unit tests actually do create a database for the unit tests in mysql, but for some reason they still require the other database that isn't actually used for the tests.

Answer (score 1):

If you run tests frequently put the following code in your settings.py:

```
import sys

if 'test' in sys.argv:
    DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'test'
    }
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't fix the problem since it tests against sqlite which is not what we deploy against and so not really a good test. But hacking up settings.py or manage.py to create the db if it doesn't exist might work.

Comment: Doesn't matters. If you're using pure django, the DB backend can change and you're site should work normally.

Answer (score 1):

I use almost the same solution for test, like @Simon Bächler, but instead of real database

```
'NAME': 'test',
```

I use

```
'NAME':' :memory:,
```

So it use memory to handle test operations, and thats why it doesn't always create/update/delete the db.